Azure ML SDKv2: Scheduled Pipeline Job Not Executing Main Script Properly
Azure ML SDKv2: Scheduled Pipeline Job Not Executing Main Script Properly
Problem:
I'm working on migrating an Azure ML project from SDKv1 to SDKv2. While my scheduled pipeline job runs successfully, the output of my main script (main.py) remains identical to the initial job submission, indicating the script isn't being re-executed.
Code:

main.py: Generates a random string on each execution and prints it along with the current timestamp.
Publish.py:

Initializes an MLClient.
Sets up an environment using Dockerfile and conda.yml.
Creates and registers a component that executes main.py.
Defines a simple pipeline with the registered component.
Submits the pipeline as a job.
Schedules the pipeline to run every 5 minutes.



Expected Behavior:
Each scheduled job execution should generate a new random string and print it along with the current timestamp.
Actual Behavior:
All scheduled job executions produce the same random string and timestamp as the initial job submission.
Code Snippets:

main.py:

import string
import random
import datetime

# using random.choices() generating random strings
res = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=10)) # initializing size of string

message_to_main = f"Hello world from scheduler... {str(res)}"

print(message_to_main)

print(f"Script execution time: {datetime.datetime.utcnow()}")


Publish.py:

# ... (relevant code for environment setup, component registration, pipeline definition, job submission, and scheduling)


# Import required libraries
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.ai.ml import command
from azure.ai.ml.dsl import pipeline
from azure.ai.ml.constants import TimeZone
from azure.ai.ml.entities import (
    Environment, BuildContext,
    JobSchedule,
    RecurrenceTrigger,
    RecurrencePattern,

)
from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceNotFoundError
from azure.ai.ml.exceptions import ValidationException


def main():
    """
    main function performs following actions:
    - Initialize MLClient handle
    - Creates or update environment for the main component which executes the logic from
        Dockerfile and conda.yml
    - Creates or update component to execute the main.py script (script is simple and does not 
        have any input and outputs)
    - Setup pipeline using main component.
    - Submit pipeline for execution as job
    - Schedule pipeline as recurring job every 5 minutes
    
    """
    
    # Set variables
    COMPUTE = "sdkv2-test-cluster"
    ENV_PATH = "."
    ENV_NAME = "helloapp_sdkv2_env_02"
    MAIN_COMPONENT_NAME = "helloapp_sdkv2_main_02"
    COMPONENT_CODE_PATH = "src"
    APP_PIPELINE_NAME = "helloapp_sdkv2_scheduler_pipeline_02"
    PIPELINE_JOB_EXPERIMENT = "helloapp_sdkv2_scheduler_experiment_02"
    JOB_SCHEDULE_NAME = "helloapp_sdkv2_scheduler_experiment_02"
    
    # get a handle to the workspace
    subscription_id="<SUBSCRIPTION ID>"
    resource_group="<RESOURCE GROUP NAME>"
    workspace="<AML WORKSPACE NAME>"
    
    ml_client = MLClient(
        DefaultAzureCredential(), subscription_id, resource_group, workspace
    )
    
    
    try:
        print(f'Starting to create environment: {ENV_NAME}')
        env_docker_context = Environment(
            build=BuildContext(path=ENV_PATH),
            name=ENV_NAME,
            description=f"Environment for {MAIN_COMPONENT_NAME}"
        )
        job_run_env =  ml_client.environments.create_or_update(env_docker_context)
        print(f'Environment creation job started for: {ENV_NAME}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise e
        
    try:
        component = command(
            name=MAIN_COMPONENT_NAME,
            compute=COMPUTE,
            # The source folder of the component
            code=COMPONENT_CODE_PATH,
            command="python main.py",
            environment=job_run_env,
        )
        # Register component for reusability
        registered_component = ml_client.create_or_update(component.component)
        print(
            f"Component {registered_component.name} with Version {registered_component.version} is registered"
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise e
        
    # Create simple pipeline
    @pipeline(name=APP_PIPELINE_NAME, compute=COMPUTE)
    def hello_sdkv2_scheduler_pipeline():
        _ = registered_component()

    app_pipeline = hello_sdkv2_scheduler_pipeline()
    
    # submit pipeline as job for execution
    submitted_job = ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(
        app_pipeline, experiment_name=PIPELINE_JOB_EXPERIMENT
    )
    print(submitted_job.id)
    
    # Schedule pipeline job for recurring execution every 5 mins
    recurrence_trigger = RecurrenceTrigger(
        frequency="minute",
        interval=5,
        time_zone=TimeZone.CENTRAL_AMERICA_STANDARD_TIME,
    )

    job_schedule = JobSchedule(
        name=JOB_SCHEDULE_NAME, 
        trigger=recurrence_trigger, 
        create_job=app_pipeline
    )

    job_schedule = ml_client.schedules.begin_create_or_update(
        schedule=job_schedule
    ).result()
    print(job_schedule)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Dockerfile:

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-ubuntu22.04

ENV AZUREML_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT_PATH /azureml-envs/helloappsdkv2

COPY conda.yml .

# Create the conda environment from the YAML file
RUN conda env create -f conda.yml -p $AZUREML_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT_PATH

# Prepend path to AzureML conda environment
ENV PATH $AZUREML_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT_PATH/bin:$PATH

RUN rm conda.yml

# This is needed for mpi to locate libpython
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH $AZUREML_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT_PATH/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH



conda.yml:

channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.12.7
  - pip
  - pip:
    - azure-ai-ml>=1.15.0

Question:
Why is the scheduled pipeline job not re-executing main.py and producing the same output as the initial job submission? What steps can I take to ensure each scheduled job execution runs main.py independently and generates a new random string?
Additional Information:

I've included screenshots of the initial job submission and subsequent scheduled executions, along with the output of main.py for each execution.
I'm using Azure ML SDKv2.

enter image description here
Outputs from Initial job and Scheduled executions

Pipeline Submit job ...
helloapp_sdkv2_scheduler_pipeline_02
Execution Time: Oct 22, 2024 11:18 am

Main Script Output:
Hello world from scheduler... VUQcztoumM
Script execution time: 2024-10-22 14:25:55.560369

Scheduler 1st Run
helloapp_sdkv2_scheduler_experiment_02-20241022T141842Z
Execution Time: Oct 22, 2024 11:18 am

Main Script Output:
Hello world from scheduler... VUQcztoumM
Script execution time: 2024-10-22 14:25:55.560369

Scheduler 2nd Run
helloapp_sdkv2_scheduler_experiment_02-20241022T142342Z
Execution Time: Oct 22, 2024 11:23 am

Main Script Output:
Hello world from scheduler... VUQcztoumM
Script execution time: 2024-10-22 14:25:55.560369

Scheduler 3rd Run
helloapp_sdkv2_scheduler_experiment_02-20241022T142842Z
Execution Time: Oct 22, 2024 11:28 am

Main Script Output:
Hello world from scheduler... VUQcztoumM
Script execution time: 2024-10-22 14:25:55.560369
Please help me understand why the scheduler is not executing main.py correctly and how to fix it.
If it is caching the result, what should be workaround for the pipelines which does not have any Inputs and Outputs.

Solved: There is setting in pipeline defination *force_rerun which is by default False. Changing that setting to True solved the issue of rerun.
app_pipeline.settings.force_rerun = True

force_rerun (boolean): Whether to force rerun the whole pipeline. The default value is False. This means that by default, the pipeline tries to reuse the output of the previous job if it meets reuse criteria. If set as True, all steps in the pipeline will rerun.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/reference-yaml-job-pipeline?view=azureml-api-2
